# Strange image title generated by c++ and opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv

Below is a very simple example using openCV to display a 2D matrix. Strangely, the image title cannot be correctly displayed. Please, any suggestion?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    Mat M(200, 200, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 255));

    string Something ("Some text");

    namedWindow("Hello", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
    imshow(Something, M);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the output you're getting? There's no reason this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code, the string passed to the namedWindow is the identifier of the window (not exactly the title).

To output an image to a window, `imshow` wants the name of a window previously created. And I guess you want to use the one you defined in `namedWindow`.

A correct code would be something like this:

```
string Something ("Some text");

namedWindow(Something, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
imshow(Something, M);
```

Maybe this is more what you like to do?

The variable Something is the identifier of the window.

Comment: The key is that you need to create a namedWindow with the same name as imshow. Good answer but I'm not sure that came across as clear enough.